# Prevent a function from being called by multiple events at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

```
element.on('click focus', function (e) {
    // Do Something
}
```

In my example, do something will be ran twice.  I want it to be ran just once per interaction.

I am using focus so users can tab into the element to fire the event OR click on it to fire the event.

The event can be fired multiple times if the user interacts with it multiple times (tabs on, then off, then on again).

Comment: You can simple declare a global Boolean variable and set it to false. When calling the function check this variable; if it's true return; else make it true and continue in the function, in the last line of the function make it false again.

Comment: Are you sure this is what you want? Any item that will be clicked must first have focus. You may be able to get away with just focus here.

Comment: So there is no built in javascripty stuff that can prevent this from happening?

Comment: Positive this is what I want.  A simple explanation is that it is a menu that will open when tabbed onto or clicked on and will close when tabbed off or clicked again.

Comment: I would suggest looking into the [`focusout`](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#focusout) or `blur` events if you want to track when an item loses focus, and the [`focusin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#focusin) event if you want to track when an item receives focus.

Comment: So what should happen if the user tabs to the menu, then clicks on the same menu? Should it close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just roll your own method that handles multiple events, using a slight timeout to throttle events so only one will be fired etc.

```
$.fn.onMulti = function() {
  var temp = [].slice.call(arguments), fn = temp.pop();

  return this.on(...temp, function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('multiTimer'));
    $(this).data('multiTimer', setTimeout(fn.bind(this, arguments), 200))
  });
}
```

```js
$.fn.onMulti = function() {
  var temp = [].slice.call(arguments), fn = temp.pop();

  return this.on(...temp, function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('multiTimer'));
    $(this).data('multiTimer', setTimeout(fn.bind(this, arguments), 200))
  });
}

/* To be used like */

var element = $('a'), i = 0;

element.onMulti('click focus', function(e) {
  console.log('works : ' + (++i));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Active Element Anchor, fires events on click and focus</a>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<div>Element to click on to remove focus</div>
```

Comment: Need to note that spread operator (**...temp**) is working in chrome version 46+. There is still some % of people using older versions like 45 and lower, such as me (since I really hate highlighting DOM updates in dev tools).

Comment: @debute - that's right. I originally wrote it [**without the spread operator**](https://jsfiddle.net/cjo5xcbe/), but decided to shorten it a bit using a spread, as everyone seems to post ES2015 answers now,

Comment: Wondering if I can lower the timeout time.  Does the delay in which the events are fired depend on the user's computer? What factors do I need to consider to make the menu feel responsive without breaking it's functionality by timing out before both events are triggered?

Comment: It mainly depends on the browser, and how fast the events are triggered etc.

Answer (score 1):

My thought is this behavior is faulty, but from your description here is a general idea to handle the events you've detailed for a menu. Working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/mcso7q1y/

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">Click Me</button>

<ul id="menu">
     <li>This is a menu.</li>
     <li>This is a menu.</li>
     <li>This is a menu.</li>
     <li>This is a menu.</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").slideUp("fast");
    var closed = true;

    $("#btn").click(function(){                       
          menuToggle(closed);
          closed = !closed;
    });

    $("#btn").focus(function(){
         menuToggle(closed);
         closed = !closed;
    });

    $("#btn").focusout(function(){
         menuToggle(closed);
         closed = !closed;
    });
});

function menuToggle(clsd){
    if(clsd){ 
        $("#menu").slideDown();          
    } else {
        $("#menu").slideUp();          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable called `done` and set it to `false` when the function is triggered only 'Do Something' if `done` is `false` and change `done` to `true` at the end of the function so if the function get's triggered again 'Do Something' won't get executed because 'done' is set to `true`

```
var done = false;

element.on('click focus', function (e) {
    if( !done ) {
        // Do Something
    }

    done = !done;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't redeclare `done` using `var` inside the event handler if you want to set the global variable.

Comment: @destoryer You should be mindful when editing code to only edit for formatting and readability and not to alter the original intent of the answers. Feel free to offer your *own* answer if you think you can improve on what others have done.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest a different tack here. Rather than dealing with global variables and all that, keep track of the state of your menu, and toggle when necessary.

```js
$(function() {
  function Menu(element) {
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.element = element;
    $(this.element).on('focusin', this.open.bind(this));
    $(this.element).on('focusout', this.close.bind(this));
    $(this.element).on('click', this.open.bind(this));
  }
  Menu.prototype.open = function() {
    this.isOpen = true;
    this.update();
  }
  Menu.prototype.close = function() {
    this.isOpen = false;
    this.update();
  }
  Menu.prototype.update = function() {
    $(this.element).toggleClass('open', this.isOpen);
  }

  $('.item').each(function (ix, el) { new Menu(el); });

});
```

```css
.item .submenu {
  display: none;
}

.item.open .submenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Submenu</li>
      <li>Submenu</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#">Menu</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>Submenu</li>
      <li>Submenu</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You might want to consider writing a jQuery plugin instead of all of that (or use one of the many existing ones).

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATED ANSWER (2023)** 
If you use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of `.on(event, fn)` you could do that in plain JavaScript like this:

```
// when element is clicked it triggers the 'focus' event before the 'click' event
element.addEventListener( 'focus', ( e ) => {  
    e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // stops event propagation
    // here goes the stuff you want to be executed once at a time
});
```

**Explanation:** 
When an element is clicked the first event to be triggered is the `focus` event which is after propagated to the `click` event. Using [Event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation) we interrupt that propagation so only one event handler will be called at a time.

The multiple output that you experience come from the `event` being  *propagated* from the `focus` event to the `click` event handler.

You could test that with this :

```
element.addEventListener( 'focus', ( e ) => clickFocusHandler( e, 'focus' ) );
element.addEventListener( 'click', ( e ) => clickFocusHandler( e, 'click' ) );

function clickFocusHandler( e, from ) {
    console.log( 'hello from:', from );
}
```

In case of `focus` event this code will ouput :

```
hello from focus
hello from focus
...
```

When it is a `click` event it will output :

```
hello from focus
hello from focus
...
hello from click
hello from click
...
```

These outputs will remain the same if you define the `click` event listener before the one used for the `focus` event.

- If you use `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the test example it will suppress the multiple outputs that comes from `event` *propagation* when a `focus` event is triggered. 
  However if you have a `click` event listener defined on the element you will have the double output when the element is clicked as the 2 listeners will be executed. **For that case** you may want to suppress that `click` listener or cancel the event using [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) with the [Event.defaultPrevented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/defaultPrevented) *property* to discard any multiple code execution for that `event`.
- If you suppress the `click` event listener you will still have the `focus` output when the element is clicked.

So the shortest version is at the top of the post if you want to use two event listeners with the same handler method it will be this longer version:

```
element.addEventListener( 'focus', ( e ) => clickFocusHandler( e ) );
element.addEventListener( 'click', ( e ) => clickFocusHandler( e ) );

function clickFocusHandler( e ) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    if ( e.defaultPrevented == false ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // here goes the stuff you want to be executed once at a time
    }
}
```

Comment: unsure how that works. It is two separate events....

Comment: @epascarello this should be clearer now...